# Undirected Graphs and Traversal on Google App Engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine, graph

I was wondering what would be the best way to implement undirected graphs (and hence graph traversal) on Google App Engine. I'm currently storing edges in the database as a list, i.e.

```
class Relation(db.Model):
    connect = db.ListProperty(str, required=True)
```

but this is notoriously inefficient.

I'm aware of the directed graph question as posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187414/storing-a-directed-graph-in-google-appengine-datastore), but I find that it would not be so suitable for an undirected graph.

Comment: Please explain why you think it is inefficient. Also please enlighten - does G.A. support stored procedures?

Comment: I have to perform a lot of queries to get all the links to the node - also I'm pretty sure App Engine doesn't support stored procedures.

Comment: Why not store your AG as a single XML string, and do all of the unpacking and traversing in regular Python?

Comment: The problem with that is I expect this graph to be huge and it would probably exceed the memory limit.

Comment: I have to admit that I am not a Google App user. Here is an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML
Now, would you elaborate more: how large is the overall graph in Gb and what data is in it and why did you settle on the Google App engine? It is possible that you want to use something else. Also, what is the typical/maximum number of edges coming out of a single vertex? And ... what does the graph traversal accomplish for you?

Are you trying to put Google out of business using the Google App engine?

Comment: I think Google App Engine is reliable and scalable which is suitable for my purpose.

Comment: I think GAE would work fine for this, and you could probably find an undirected graph solution. Could you give us a list of what functions you'd likely perform most?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would store the graph as a directed graph, which allows you to use queries more effectively. Obviously you need to have the constraint that all directed edges must have a partnering edge going in the opposite direction.

```
Class Vertex(db.Model):
   #Vertex specific stuff

Class Edge(db.Model):
   Start = db.ReferenceProperty(Vertex)
   End = db.ReferenceProperty(Vertex)
```

You can then pull out all of the edges relating to a specific vertex with a simple query:

```
#getting all neighbours of a vertex called "foo"
Neighbours = Edge.all()
Neighbours.filter("Start = ", foo)
#neighbours now contains a set of all edges leading from foo
```

Nice and simple, taking advantage of the fact you're using appengine so you can let indexing do a lot of the work for you ;)

If you want to make sure that directed constraint remains true, obviously use a method to create edges like so:

```
LinkVertices(A, B) #A and B are vertices
   edgeOne = Edge()
   edgeOne.Start = A
   edgeOne.End = B
   edgeOne.put()

   edgeTwo = Edge()
   edgeTwo.Start = B
   edgeTwo.End = A
   edgeTwo.put()
```

Addressing roffles concerns about storing all the edges twice, you could try something like this:

```
Class Edge(db.Model):
    A = db.ReferenceProperty(Vertex)
    B = db.ReferenceProperty(Vertex)

#getting all neighbours of a vertex called "foo"
Neighbours = Edge.all()
Neighbours.filter("A = ", foo)
OtherNeighbours = Edge.all()
OtherNeighbours.filter("B = ", foo)
#these two queries now contains all edges leading from foo.
```

This approach basically saves you storage space (every edge is only stored once) at the cost of slightly higher query times and much messier code. In my opinion that's not a very good tradeoff, since you're saving yourself about 64 bytes storage per edge.

Comment: Oh I like this, though I really would like an undirected graph implementation :)

Comment: you can delete comments for when you have a mild brain explosion ;)

Does this satisfy your requirements then?

Comment: I'm concerned about the fact I'll need two edges per link though - 500 undirected edges gets turned into 1000 directed ones. That can't be good for App Engine.

Comment: Well the edges are fairly lightweight in terms of storage space. I wouldn't worry about it - it's CPU time you should be more worried about in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for this. What about ancestors - guess the edges should have some parents. Either a sharded edges_root or that the node is parent to it's edge? edgeOne.Start = A; edgeOne.parent = A; edgeTwo.Start = B; edgeTwo = B; Or am I wrong? Guess you don't really need the start node as it's the same as parent and is never changed

Comment: By ancestors I assume you mean the origin vertex of an edge? If so, I think you answered your own question - just use the start node.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this misses something about the problem, but why can't you have an edge class that holds max two vertex refs in a list? This would let you use an equality query to fetch all edges for a given vertex and it doesn't require duplication.

```
Class Edge(db.Model):
   Vertices = db.ListProperty(db.ReferenceProperty(Vertex))

...

edges = Edge.all()
edges.filter("Vertices = ", foo)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could store the vertex' ends as a list of keys, but you would need to update two vertex to create a new connection.

```
class Vertex(db.Model):
    ends= db.ListProperty(db.Key)
    # Other information about the vertex here
```

If you are not worried about the writing time, this may be a good solution.